# Using range slider with reactjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I have used angularjs in the past. whenever I had to use some additional components I could simply use jQuery/ jQuery UI components but I find its very difficult with reactjs.

For example:
I wanted to use range slider. by using jQuery, its very easy, even by using HTML5 its very easy, but if I have to use range slider, I have to write it myself (some of the npm modules for range look very basic).

I have two questions:

1. Is there any better way to include range slider with reactjs ?
2. It seems its hard to add features like this with react (*I am newbie, please bear with my ignorance*) then why everybody thinks reactjs is better than other frameworks and its getting more traction ?

Comment: You can hook up jQuery plugins in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle callback. I'm not sure what the problem with using `<input type="range" />` is but you certainly don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: thanks, this did answer my question about slider. Can you please throw some light on my second question ?
Instead of using react, Can I use handlebars, jQuery and Bootstrap to develop fairly simple webapp ?

Comment: You can use whatever you prefer. I'm still maintaining apps written in Backbone and they work just fine. I prefer React but that's my personal opinion, there is no single truth about what is "best". If you want to use handlebars and jQuery then go ahead and do it.